# Parameterized Query in SQL command with method

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-injection, parameterized-query

Right now I want to make this a parameterized query so that it is not prone to SQL injection. This is the code:

```
 string sqlText = "SELECT @EmployeeColumn FROM Test_Attachments WHERE Project_Id = @PID1 AND [Directory] = '" + qAttachment.Directory1.Replace("\\\\" + Root_Directory, "") + "' ";

 try 
 {
     SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlText, SqlConnection);

     myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmployeeColumn", Employee_Column);
     myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("PID1", Project_ID1");
 }
 .....
```

How do I make the query parameterized? Especially with the method. Thanks

EDIT:
Sorry. I Was typing this on mobile so it has many typos. Thanks!

Comment: This is like 4 mistakes rolled into one statement. Why don't you try something simple like one parameter first and get that to work?

Comment: Side note:  You should not have apostrophes around your `@PID1` variable.

Answer (score 0):

PID1 is parameterized already, so you could something similar for Directory. There is another issue in the SELECT clause, AddWithValue doesn't work to choose what columns to project in the SELECT, but you can have a validation for that (I'v added an example with everything inline but it should be refactored further)

```
string sqlText = "SELECT {{columnName}} FROM Test_Attachments WHERE Project_Id =@PID1 AND [Directory] = @Directory";

var allowedColumns = new List<string>{"columnA", "columnB"};

if(allowedColumns.Contains(Employee_Column)
{
   sqlText = sqlText.Replace("{{columnName}}", Employee_Column);
} 
else
{
   throw new Exception($"Invalid Column {Employee_Column}");
}

try {
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlText, SqlConnection);

    var directory = qAttachment.Directory1.Replace("\\\\" + Root_Directory, "");

     myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PID1", Project_ID1);
     myCommand.Parameters.AddwithValue("@Directory", directory);

     ...
}
```

Comment: OP wants to avoid SQL injection vulnerability. Your answer is still vulnerable.

Comment: I was under the impression that the use of SqlParamterCollection (myCommand.Parameters) has the mechanism to prevent injection by templating the query and limiting the scope of the variables that are passed in . Can you elaborate on how  it doesn't prevent then? what would you change to prevent that?

Comment: My bad, I’m on mobile so I did not see your logic for filtering columnName. It’s not 100% full proof but it’s enough of a check I suppose.

Comment: Thanks @adglopez. Im gonna try this and execute in veracode